# Finding Critical Points and Local Maxima/Minima or Saddle Point

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I need help to find critical points of the function:
$$f(x,y)=\frac{-x^3}{3}+x-y^2$$
Then I have to classify these critical points as local maxima/minima or saddle points.

I thought that to find the critical points, I have to find the 1st derivative and to find local max/min or saddle, I have to use the second derivative test. I am having a little trouble both in finding first and second derivatives and how to use it to find the given above. Can someone help me?

Edit: I found the critical points to be $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$. Can someone verify this as well?

Comment: Yepp, you are right.

Comment: @user251257 So how do I continue on with this?

Comment: Like you said. You compute the 2nd derivative, the Hessian matrix at the critical points. If the Hessian is positive definite, you have a local minimum. If it is negative definite, you have a local maximum. If is is indefinite, you have a saddle point.

Comment: @user251257 I haven't seen the hessian matrix before. Can you please show me how this is done in this case?

Comment: The Hessian is 
$$ \nabla^2 f(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(x,y) & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}(x,y) \\ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}(x,y) & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(x,y) \end{bmatrix}.$$ 
For example $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}f(x,y) = \frac{d}{dy}(-2y) = -2$.

Comment: @user251257 Can you set it up for me for this case, and I'll try to work from there?

Comment: Just try. It is just differentiation. There is no magic :)

Comment: @user251257 My mind just went blank. How do you find $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}$?

Comment: First differentiate $f$ with respect to $x$, then differentiate the result with respect to $y$.

Comment: @user251257 So I got $f_x=-x^2+1-y^2$, so it would be $-2y$?

Comment: $f_x(x,y) = -x^2+1$.

Comment: @user251257 Oh true, so would it be 0?

Comment: Yes, I get that too.

Comment: Okay so I found the matrix, now what do I do?

Comment: Check for the three type of definiteness. Since the Hessian is diagonal, the diagonal elements are also its eigenvalues. So you could use some eigenvalue criterion to determine the definiteness of the Hessian.

Comment: @user251257 I'm really having trouble. Can you please post a solution explanation if you don't mind. I am stuck. It's irritating to me that I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You have $$\nabla f(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} -x^2 + 1 \\ - 2y \end{bmatrix}.$$
So the critical points are $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$.

Now, the Hessian is
$$\nabla^2 f(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} -2x & 0 \\ 0 & -2 \end{bmatrix}.$$
The eigenvalues of $\nabla^2 f(-1,0)$ are $2$ and $-2$. Thus, $\nabla^2 f(-1,0)$ is indefinite and $(-1,0)$ is a saddle point. The eigenvalues of $\nabla^2 f(1,0)$ are $-2$ and $-2$. Thus, $\nabla^2 f(1,0)$ is negative definite and $(1,0)$ is a maximum.

Comment: What do you mean by negative definite?

Comment: A (symmetric) matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is negative definite if and only if for every $x\in\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ it follows $x^T A x < 0$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix

Comment: Can you show this?

Comment: @Neel: What exactly?

Comment: @Neel $A$ represents a quadratic form; when $A$ is diagonal you get $x^T Ax=\sum\lambda_i x_i^2$, so when all $\lambda_i<0$ we get $x^T Ax=\sum\lambda_i x_i^2> 0$, when all $\lambda_i>0$ you have $x^T Ax\ge0$, and otherwise it's indefinite (note this is for nonzero $x$).